# Separate backend "Widgets" page for each language

Tags: widgets, theme-options, options, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

Im currently trying to make my backend work with multiple languages.
Im using qTranslate as my translation plugin.

So far I have accomplished a custom option page with multi-language support. When you click on a different language *(in qTranslate on the sidebar)* you will get a new options page with prepared option-variables

```
show(option_textarea) -> 'english backend' -> show(option_textarea_en)
(saving under the same variable possible)
```

So, if I use one of the options in my template im just accessing the option with the current active language

```
give(option_logo) -> 'german page viewing' -> return option_logo_de
```

This also works on the widget-page-side. EXCEPT, when I'm switching my current language in the backend each widget gets the status 'unused' and I have to manually put in the widgets again. They don't exist for the current active language and are not faved. So in general I can only set widgets for one language at a time. The widgets from the other language i have set are dropped then. How can I deactivate this behaviour?

What I need is a fixed widget-editing system that works the same way as my options. Maybe there is a workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ehm... everyone sleeping or is it the awesome weekend? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how qTraslate works, but you can pass filters to [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) , you basically duplicate each widget, one for each language. I have used this technique with WPML to show widgets in separate languages that can sometimes be difficult ( such as when they make direct DB queries).

Comment: i'll accept this as it seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: I want to add I have had some problems with Widget Logic recently and found another great plugin called http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/ that works well.

Answer (score 2):

As Wyck points out, that's the easiest way.

I have the following function in my `functions.php` and use it to filter a bunch of duplicated widgets, one for each language, e.g.: `is_lingo('en')`, `is_lingo('pt')`, etc...

```
function is_lingo( $what ) 
{
    if ( !function_exists('qtrans_getLanguage') )
        return false;

    $lingo = qtrans_getLanguage(); 

    if( $what == $lingo ) 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```